# How to install NetCDF4 module in Spyder?

Tags: python, module, spyder, netcdf4

I don't know why this is causing me so much headache.

I know how to use pip, and have the latest version, but still when running a script in Spyder that requires netCDF4 (import netCDF4) Spyder always returns:

```py
import netCDF4
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netCDF4'"
```

1. I opened cmd, pip install netCDF4, confirmed it installed OK. Shouldn't this be enough?
2. I manually copied a downloaded version of netCDF4, moved it to my Python site packages, and then in Spyder manually went into PYTHONPath Manager -> Add Path --> Added the folder location 'netCDF4-1.6.0'. I thought this would definitely be enough?
3. Then INSIDE Spyder's python console, bot-right of screen, I tried 'pip install netCDF4' and it returns:

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
C:\...\Spyder\Python\python.exe: No module named pip
```

So is my issue #3? Spyder's version of Python doesn't have pip and doesn't link to the netCDF4 module? I thought my step #2 would resolve this?

Any help on how to install modules in Spyder would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It seems like you’re using an environment manager that is different t from the system env. Maybe venv or conda? If so you need to connect spider to that environment. Spider has docs on how to do this - the process will differ based on how you installed python and pip. Start with calling `where pip` from the terminal where you installed netCDF.

Comment: Thanks! I found pip installed on my C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts folder. Do I add this entire "scripts" folder to my Python Path manager?

Comment: I don't know. but it seems like you're getting way too hands-on with all this manually adding paths and moving files around. that is a good way to end up in a real nightmare. I'd download miniconda, install all the packages you want in a new environment, e.g. `conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge python=3.9 netcdf4 [others ...]` and then follow the spider docs for adding a conda env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and install all the packages you want in a new environment.  For example,

```bash
conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge python=3.9 netcdf4 [others ...]
```

Then follow the [Spyder documentation](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/index.html) for adding a `conda` environment.

Credit to Michael Delgado (above)